# Writing starting from a certain line number in a text file

Tags: bash, bash-script

In a bash script I want to write some lines to a text file, but this file has already been used before and there are texts in it. So I want to echo some additional text in it, starting from a certain line number in the file.

I want something like this:

```
echo -fromLineNumber 33 -e "anything" >> textPath
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `sed` to write at a particular line.

try this:

```
    sed -i '33ianything' textpath
```

or

```
    sed -i '33i\anything' textpath
```

It will insert "anything" in line number 33.

Comment: It should work. Works fine for me in bash 4.2 and sed 4.2 in ubuntu.

Comment: wait a minute i will try again

Comment: Thanks it works , it was my mistake in the first place thank u very much

Comment: can i write it like this `sed -i '$numberkanything' textPath` out i must write down the number of line directly

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein, the shell will not expand variables within single quotes. Also you have to tell the shell how to differentiate the variable name from the following text: `sed -i "${number}i\anything" file`

Comment: in case anything was a variable value also the \ will make a problem to the $ in case i want to use the one with \ `sed -i "${number}i\$anything" file` so any idea about how to skip that

Answer (score 2):

To keep the first 32 lines and add new text afterwards:

```
head -n 32 oldfile > newfile
echo anything >> newfile
echo goes >> newfile
echo here >> newfile
```

To insert some text after line 32 of a file:

```
sed -e '32s/$/\nanything\ngoes\nhere/' oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: thank u , but i want to append on the old text file my new texts after a certain line number not to add in new file  , i hope that i can make myself clear?