# bash: how do I write base64-encoded content into a file to specified line

Tags: bash, base64

I'm working on an "edgemax feature-wizard" which is kind of a plugin system.
There are only three files allowed in a plugin tarball: a bash script as backend, a HTML file as frontend and a validation.json file for input validation from frontend, so please don't ask why I don't just put the deb packages into the tarball -- they get ignored.

I want to ship deb packages with that "wizard" so I have to base64 encode the files and put it into the bash script to be extracted when the script is run.
Now, I know how to do all this, but I'm doing it manually by copy-pasting the base64 part into the bash file and then cut-paste into right position, which is unhandy when updating those packages to recent version.

Would there be a possibility to encode the deb files in base64 and write it to line 65 of the bash script?

I've read [this article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75803/writing-starting-from-a-certain-line-number-in-a-text-file) and I tried

```
sed -i "65i\\$(base64 package.deb)" wizard-run
```

but that complains with:

```
bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

Here's my code; the base64-part has to go within the double-quotes from the echo statement:

```
if [ $arch == 'mips' ]; then
    # base64: olsrd_0.9.0.3-1_mips.deb
    echo "
    <base64encoded-pkg>
    " | base64 -d > $cfgusrdir/olsrd_0.9.0.3-1_mips.deb
    # base64: olsrd-plugins_0.9.0.3-1_mips.deb
    echo "
    <base64encoded-pkg>
    " | base64 -d > $cfgusrdir/olsrd-plugins_0.9.0.3-1_mips.deb
fi
```

Comment: use a here document

Comment: +1 to the heredoc - however, at least if you have GNU sed, you could probably do `base64 package.deb | sed -i '65r /dev/stdin' wizard-run`

Comment: great, that did it, thanks! is there a way to also remove newline at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` and I/O redirection:

```
{
  sed -n '1,64p' wizard-run;
  base64 package.deb;
  sed -n '66,$p' wizard-run;
} > wizard-run.tmp && mv wizard-run.tmp wizard-run
```

Comment: good idea, but i dont understand why, that fills the wizard-run with the base64 part running in loop until i press ctrl+c ..

Comment: @vchrizz Oops, writing to the file you are writing to is a bad idea (see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094). My bad, will fix it.

Comment: ok that worked now, how do i remove newline from beginning and end?

Comment: @vchrizz Beginning and end of what? `wizard-run`?

Comment: ive added my code to clarify. at the moment the line is beeing replaced by the base64 and it has to be within the quotes without newlines and/or spaces for the script to work.

Comment: @vchrizz Try the `-i` parameter of `base64`.